# Blazor server route prefix dynamic

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an Blazor server Application and we need to set up an global route prefix that we can use to set specific data based on the prefix. Is there any solution for that?

Ex. We want this /company/{companyID}/
To be on Every route and have a Middleware or something similar to cath the companyID in.

```
endpoints.MapGet("/company/{companyID:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{{3,100}}(-[a-zA-Z+]{{3,100}})?$)}/{**rest}", async context =>
                {
                    var companyID = context.Request.RouteValues["companyID"]?.ToString()?.ToLower() ?? "default";
                    var restPath = context.Request.RouteValues["rest"]?.ToString()?.ToLower();

// Here i do stuff with the CompanyID
                    
                    // This is for now, but will redirect to /index without company/companyID. Here i just want to go on with the Ondex component and keep the url.
                    context.Response.Redirect(restPath == null ? "/" : $"/{restPath}");
                });
                
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

Comment: Yes, but specifics?  Where for example does `/company/{companyID}/ Index` and `/company/{companyID}/Index` for example route to?  And were does `/Index` route to?

Comment: It will goes to a blazor component that has the @page "/index". So i want to catch the companyID global to set a cookie or a state that i can use in my components. Today i have an endpoints.MapGet in my startup that catch /company/{companyID}/**rest. And there i do the work to set a cookie with the companyID but then i have to redirect to /index to hit the component, but i want to keep the /company/{companyID}/index url insteda of redirect to just /index.

Comment: Updated orginal post with example.

Comment: So does every route in your Blazor App contain the company.  e.g.  `/company/{companyID}/Index`, `/company/{companyID}/Counter`, `/company/{companyID}/FetchData`.  Or is this just the "Startup" link?

Comment: No its not its contains only /Index /Counter etc. Even if i add that it will not work.

Comment: Have a look at URL Rewriting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#url-rewriting-sample-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may fit your requirements.  It uses LocalStorage to persist the company name instead of cookies.  I've set it up using the Blazor Server template.

Install `Blazored.LocalStorage`

First a Company Service

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

namespace Blazor.Company;

public class CompanyService
{
    private ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

    public const string CompanyNameKey = "CompanyName";

    public string CompanyName { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public CompanyService(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
        => _localStorageService = localStorageService;

    public async Task SetCompany(string company)
    {
        this.CompanyName = company;
        await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync<string>(CompanyNameKey, company);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetCompany()
    {
        this.CompanyName = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(CompanyNameKey);
        return this.CompanyName;
    }
}
```

Program looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CompanyService>();
```

`Index` looks like this:

```
page "/"
@page "/Company"
@page "/Company/{CompanyName}"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

@if (this.hasCompany && this.isSet)
{
    <div class="m-2 p-4 bg-success text-white">
        <h3>You work for : @CompanyService.CompanyName</h3>
    </div>
}
@if (this.isSet && !this.hasCompany)
{
    <div class="m-2 p-4 bg-danger text-white">
        You need to set up your company
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string CompanyName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    private string companyName = string.Empty;

    private bool isSet = false;
    private bool hasCompany => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.companyName);

    [Inject] private CompanyService? companyService { get; set; }
    private CompanyService CompanyService => companyService!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.CompanyName))
            companyName = this.CompanyName;
    }

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.companyName))
                companyName = await CompanyService.GetCompany();
            else
                await CompanyService.SetCompany(companyName);

            this.isSet = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, i implemented a similar solution with an middleware that listen to every request and then set companyID based on path and if not exsist in path set based on localstorage or find correct companyID based on user. A also make an own navigationservice to handle company on every navigateto request. I will mark your answer as accepted. That a dont have solved yet is to skip @page attribute with company/{companyID} on every page it would be nice if i dont need to add that. Maybee it will work with an baseComponent inherihiet from?!

Comment: If your interested, I've written a custom Navigation Manager and lightly customized Router to manage form state.  I'm pretty sure you could adapt the Navigation Manager to remove the company stuff from the Url i.e. take `/Company/CEC/Index` as the incoming route and pass the router `/Index`.  The Repo is here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.EditForm

Comment: Nice, i will look into that. Thx.